# Write multiple lists to different files

Tags: python

I would like to write to disk the contents of different lists.

```
>>> dev = ['toto', 'tata']
>>> env = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> prod = ['baz']
```

The named file should have the same name as the list, therefore I would like  three files called `dev`, `env` and `prod`; with each file containing only the corresponding list.

So far I tried to write lists to files using this:

```
 with open('prod', 'w') as file_handler:    
         for item in list(prod):           
               file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Is a Pythonic way to loop over the lists and write the contents to files?

I would like to perform this by looping through a data structure like so:

```
file_list = ['env', 'dev', 'prod']
```

How can I loop over it to create a file for each list?

Thank you.

Comment: Write that code in a function that takes a name and a list as arguments.

Comment: could you elaborate? please...

Comment: There isn't much to add. Don't you know how to write and use functions? (Don't try to use the variable name as the file name. It will make things complex and confusing.)

Comment: or you can useanotherfor loop above _open_, `for file_name in file_list: with open(f'{file_name}', 'w') as file_handler: ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way is to build a better data structure of your configuration (from the lists names i suppose you are trying to build an environment configuration)

You could achieve this by create a dict and loop through it :

```
my_lists = {
    'dev': ['toto', 'tata'],
    'env': ['foo', 'bar'],
    'prod': ['baz'],
}


for list_name, list_content in my_lists.items():
    with open(list_name, 'w') as file_handler:
        for item in list_content:
            file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

or you could write a function to a better re-using :

```py
    def write_list_to_file(list_name, list_content):
        with open(list_name, 'w') as file_handler:
            for item in list_content:
                file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))


    for list_name, list_content in my_lists.items():
        write_list_to_file(list_name, list_content)
```

**EDIT**

You could also use the locals object (which is by the way a dict as i suggested) as suggested in @LeoArad's answer . So it might matches your need too, i would not do so because it will loops through **all** entries in the locals object which might be less efficient than using a better data structure from the begining

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `locals()` if there are only those lists in the local scope (if there are other lists, it will create files for them too).

```
dev = ['toto', 'tata']
env = ['foo', 'bar']
prod = ['baz']

# check for each object in the locals object, if they are instances of list class, and if yes, create a file for each lists
for name, ls in {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, list)}.items():
    with open(name, 'w') as file_handler:
        for item in ls:
            file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Comment: This could works but this will also create a loop through all the entry of the `locals()` object and check for instances of lists O(n) where n is an entry of `locals` instance.... might be a little bit costly and overkill (?) I suggested to create a dictionary which is a O(1) data structure

Comment: the lists are actually of several hundred items each so i guess this has an impact

Comment: @zn553 if there is only lists in your locals : the impact is not so important and maybe you will not have to check for `isinstance` method....but again the problem is if you got other objects that you dont need to write....this will loop through them too this why the complexity here is O(n)....SO it realy suggests you to build a better data structure for this purpose

Comment: Of curse creating a dictionary from the begging is the best way to handle this question but the create a dictionary for several hundred lists will be more costly. Since the PO already have it stored in variables it will be a problem to map them all to a dictionary.

Comment: @LeoArad : this is why i suggested to build a better data structure from the begining....not mapping through existing list and copy them to a new struct (even if it copy them by reference so the cost is not so bad...). Just build a HashMap (dict in python) from the begining with the desired lists inside

Comment: To build a new my_lists variable with a dictionary that contains several hundred key values manually will cost more time then python loop over all items in the locals dictionary. This answer is to work with the existing code not to refactor it. @zn553 to iterate over several hundred items in python is not causing a performance issue.

Comment: @LeoArad : when i saw this code i saw environment configuration. Now the thing is that configuration is generaly achieved in a configuration file which is then converted to a data structure. I never seen a professional program with hard coded configuration in a code file...now the configuration structure is often implemented as a dictionary because of its random acsess. This is why i suggested a better data structure for this kind of usecase.

Comment: @LeoArad : you said "@zn553 to iterate over several hundred items in python is not causing a performance issue." .... Of course iteration has a cost and no matters if its  a python, a golang or a Java program...this cost is evaluated by Algorithmic efficiency therory and has nothing to do with the technology you are using (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) so the more iteration it has the more costly a program is...

Comment: @LeoArad : .you can argue that some technologies manage iteration better than others....but once you decided to go with one technology that manage it better, this does not mean that you can implement any algorithm that you want regardless of the number of iterations

Comment: @yAzou you got me wrong I meant that to iterate over several hundred items will make a few milliseconds differences so to compare it to manually write a dictionary that has several hundred keys, values items it will take much longer. so you thought that I wrote that it will not make any performance differences it's only from the millisecond's point of view and of course it's will have a few milliseconds differences.

Comment: the dictionamy will have only 3 keys based on my example I am wondering how can i build a dictionary where the values of a key is a relatively long list using collections?

Comment: update: i could not use this with locals() there were other lists in my code that did not need to be written.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to yAzou's answer

```
my_lists = {
    'dev': ['toto', 'tata'],
    'env': ['foo', 'bar'],
    'prod': ['baz'],
}


for list_name, list_content in my_lists.items():
    with open(list_name, 'w') as file_handler:
            file_handler.write("\n".join(list_content))
```